# Select currency and show commas and/or decimals in the input

Tags: javascript

I have a select (currency) and an input (amount)

The input has to show thousands separators (commas `,`) for all the currencies and two decimals `.00` for all the currencies as well (except for `JPY`) in real time while the user is typing.

Example input: (JPY) `123456789`

Desired result: `123,456,789`

Example input: (USD) `123456789.94`

Desired result: `123,456,789.94`

**What I've tried**:

Using `toLocaleString()`:

```
$("#valueInput").on('keyup',function(){
    $("#valueInput").val($("#valueInput").val().toLocaleString());
});
```

Using `split` and `replace`:

```
$("#valueInput").on('keyup',function(){
    $("#valueInput").val($("#valueInput").val().split(',').join(''));
    $("#valueInput").val(($("#valueInput").val()).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    $("#estimatedValue").val($("#estimatedValueSelect option:selected").text() + " " + $("#valueInput").val());
});
```

Using `toLocaleString()` & specifiying a format:

```
$("#valueInput").on('keyup',function(){
    var value = $("#valueInput").val();
    $("#valueInput").val(value.toLocaleString('en'));
});
```

None of them worked.

**Full code:**

```js
$('#valueSelect').on('change', function(){
    if(this.value === 'JPY') {
        $("#valueInput").removeAttr("pattern");
        $("#valueInput").removeAttr("placeholder");
        $("#valueInput").removeAttr("min");
        $("#valueInput").removeAttr("step");
        $("#valueInput").attr("pattern","[0-9]");
        $("#valueInput").attr("title","Numbers only");
        $("#valueInput").attr("placeholder","1000");
    } else {
        $("#valueInput").removeAttr("placeholder");
        $("#valueInput").attr("pattern","^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$");
        $("#valueInput").attr("placeholder","0.00");
        $("#valueInput").attr("min","0");
        $("#valueInput").attr("step","0.01");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-sm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <select  id="valueSelect" class="selectpicker"  aria-label="Currency">
                    <option value="JPY" selected>JPY</option>
                    <option value="USD">USD</option>
                    <option value="EUR">EUR</option> 
                </select>
            </div>
            <input id="valueInput" class="form-control" aria-label="Estimated Value" type="number" placeholder="1000" name="price" pattern="[0-9]" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also implemented the validation part and it works partially, what I can't get to work is displaying a comma `,` and period `.` in real time while the user is typing with the restrictions mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my approach based on your code:

1. Remove restriction by HTML `pattern` and change `input` type to `text`
2. Use `oninput` event handler to remove disallowed characters and convert the number to desired format

```js
let maximumFractionDigits = 0
const valueInput = $("#valueInput");
const formatNumber = (value) => {
  return parseFloat(value.replace(/,/g,'')).toLocaleString('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits });
}

$('#valueSelect').on('change', function(){
  if(this.value === 'JPY') {
    maximumFractionDigits = 0
    valueInput.removeAttr("pattern");
    valueInput.removeAttr("placeholder");
    valueInput.removeAttr("min");
    valueInput.removeAttr("step");
    valueInput.attr("title","Numbers only");
    valueInput.attr("placeholder","1000");
  } else {
    maximumFractionDigits = 2
    valueInput.removeAttr("placeholder");
    valueInput.attr("pattern","^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$");
    valueInput.attr("placeholder","0.00");
    valueInput.attr("min","0");
    valueInput.attr("step","0.01");
  }
  valueInput.val(formatNumber(valueInput.val()));
});

valueInput.on('input', function() {
  if (!this.value || (maximumFractionDigits && this.value.endsWith('.'))) {
    return
  }
  $(this).val(formatNumber(this.value));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-sm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <select  id="valueSelect" class="selectpicker"  aria-label="Currency">
                    <option value="JPY" selected>JPY</option>
                    <option value="USD">USD</option>
                    <option value="EUR">EUR</option> 
                </select>
            </div>
            <input id="valueInput" class="form-control" aria-label="Estimated Value" type="text" placeholder="1000" name="price" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Woah thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for. Just one thing: If I input decimals let's say with EUR and then switch back to JPY, the decimals should disappear. How can we do that?

Comment: @Cheknov I just updated my answer, pls check it

Comment: Thanks! commas are working well but decimal points `.` are not working and I'm getting a `NaN` message when running your snippet. Btw I like how decimals are rounded, very smart!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat). From the documentation:

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US',).format(123456789.94));
```

You can use any language format you want.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, could you provide further details?